# Выражение "Ну как насчёт завтра?"

Tags: грамотная-речь, части-речи

Нормально ли будет так сказать в простом разговоре?

Если нет, то можно его заменить на что-то простое, более подходящее разговорной речи, чем:

> Ну как насчёт **завтрашнего дня**?

***Кстати!***

Написал *"подходящее разговорной речи".* Так можно или правильно только *"**для** разговорной речи"?*

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Ведь **завтра** наречие, а не существительное._  === Нет, не так. Может быть наречием, может быть и существительным среднего рода... См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0&all=x ЗАВТРА. <...> II. неизм.; ср. Следующий день за сегодняшним. _Распорядок дня на з. Могу остаться до з.? * Не нужно откладывать на завтра то, что можно сделать сегодня_ (Посл.).

Comment: Да, точно, смотрел там, но не прописали напрямую, что существительное, вот и не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из толкового словаря Д. В. Дмитриева:
[**насчёт**](http://endic.ru/dmytriev/Nascht-1830.html), = относительно, по поводу
**2.** Вы используете выражение **как насчёт** в начале вопроса, если хотите предложить или обсудить что-либо.
***Как насчёт*** завтрака? **Как насчёт** кружки пива? **Как насчёт** того, чтобы сдать квартиру в аренду?

*— Только не сегодня. Я очень устала, – отказалась Лариса.

— А как насчет завтра?*
(С. Алешина. Мимо кассы)

В словаре управления:
[подходящий](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Podhodjaschij-24349.html), ***для кого*** и **кому**, **для чего** и **на что.**
Подходящие для нас (нам) условия найма. Площадка, подходящая для постройки (на постройку) гаража.

Так что, думаю, правильно говорить *подходящее **для** разговорной речи* (для чего).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: И Вам спасибо за интересный вопрос — ответы нашлись _не сразу._